# What to write in target and values for selecting button inside form in Selenium Plugin ide

Tags: selenium-ide

I have a Form inside which i am having a submit button but that submit button is not having any name it is only having Value. 
Please help me how can i select myButton. I am using selenium plugin ide in mozilla.

It is like

Comment: <form action="A.jsp" target="B" name="C">
<input type = "hidden" value ="" name ="D"/>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="submit" value="myButton"/>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<table>
</form>

Answer (score 0):

You can use either CSS or Xpath :

below is the code :

Xpath
//*[@*='submit']

Regards,
Tarun